# JQuery Mobile List/Detail view

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a JQuery Mobile List view that looks like this:

```
 {
     "title": "Available Cars",
     "names": [
         {
             "name": "Ford",
             "image": "./images/ford.png",
             "flags": "./images/us.png",
             "description": "Make Average Cars",
             "detail": [
                 {
                     "Profile": "Big US company",
                     "Background": "Started some time ago"
                 }
             ]
         },
         {
             "name": "BWM",
             "image": "./images/bmw.png",
             "flags": "./images/gm.png",
             "description": "Make Great Cars",
             "detail": [
                 {
                     "Profile": "MediumGermancompany",
                     "Background": "Startedsometimeago"
                 }
             ]
         },
         {
             "name": "VW",
             "image": "./images/vw.png",
             "flags": "./images/gm.png",
             "description": "MakeGoodCars",
             "detail": [
                 {
                     "Profile": "LargeGermancompany",
                     "Background": "Startedsometimeago"
                 }
             ]
         }
     ]
 }
```

This JSON is being dynamically rendered to the appropriate HTML using my templating library which create a simple list view based on the name and associated images in the first level.

I want to render the data within the "description": sections into a detail view of the data. Thus, when the list item is clicked it transitions to a detail view.

Since I already have all of the required data, I don't need to make a further request to the server.

I've completed the first part and heres a jsfiddle that shows it working:

http://jsfiddle.net/carlskii/7WK7P/30/

Could somebody please suggest a way to do this since can't seem to find any decent examples here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well since [jQuery Mobile is about to deprecate nested Lists](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/listviews/#list-nested) your best bet is plain old navigation. Make a page with the desired link (the name in your template for example):

```
<div data-role="page" data-url="/damyanpetev/7WK7P/36/show/light/Ford">
        TEST PAGE FOR FORD
</div>
```

And make the 'href' in your item template to be the name as well and it will both naviogate and keep a history stack and all the goodness :) See the help for [AJAX NAvigation](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/navigation/).

Here's my modified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/damyanpetev/7WK7P/36/ (see below for the actual demo part)

P.S.: jsFiddle makes it really hard to nail links for me.. so this will only navigate properly out of all the frames - http://fiddle.jshell.net/damyanpetev/7WK7P/36/show/light/

Comment: Nice! - Thanks very much for the tip!!

Is it me but does the page rendering between the pages seem a bit clunky?. i.e. I get a quick glimpse of some unstyled HTML!!

Comment: Yup that's the test list you append at the end of the script - since it's in the body (outside of jQuery Mobile page) it's visible during transitions. Without the test list - http://fiddle.jshell.net/damyanpetev/7WK7P/39/show/light/ :)